# haskell basic telnet network socket example 2

Tags: haskell, telnet

```
module Main where
import Network
import Network.Socket
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
 addrInfos <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just "localhost") (Just "23")
 s <- socket (addrFamily (head addrInfos)) Stream defaultProtocol
 connect s (addrAddress (head addrInfos))
 h <- socketToHandle s ReadWriteMode
 hSetBuffering h (BlockBuffering Nothing)

 l <- hGetLine h
 putStrLn l
```

I am trying to make a haskell example of howto login and send receive some hardcoded telnet line commands. So far I have something like this. I expected to see "login:" on the screen but it shows nothing?

Comment: Using netcat, which you should probably learn to use for testing basic connectivity, this code connects to a TCP server fine.  It also echoed what I typed into the `nc` server.  If it isn't working for your telnet server then I suggest you check the obvious things (ports, IPs, telnet server, etc).

Comment: nc -l 23 works for me too so I guess it means telnetd is expecting some kind of handshake char. Anyway I will try to figure out how the telnet protocol works and make yet a other question if I am stuck. Why this can not be discussed in one question without being closed is beyond me.

Comment: It's not so clear that you've done your homework here, which may contribute to why you're not getting a lot of positive response. Questions like "will you write me code that connects to a telnet server" aren't really polite. However, perhaps you will like [RFC 854](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854), which may also help you formulate a more specific question.

Comment: That I understand, but then you should state it in a comment without closing that you will not give me any answer. So I can specify more to the point where you feel satisfied. Also keep in mind that I expected this to be a much simpler answer comparing it with my python solution or at least been done before by many, so i do not need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [haskell basic telnet network socket example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595079/haskell-basic-telnet-network-socket-example)

Comment: @GertCuykens: Even though it's closed, you can still edit your original question to fix it and then flag to have it re-opened. Posting the exact same question twice is not the way to do it.

Comment: I can not reopen because I have not enough exp and it has been edited to be a exact copy of this one. It should not have been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use BlockBuffering Nothing. Use NoBuffering. The haddocks are very clear that BlockBuffering Nothing gives implementation-dependent buffering, not no buffering. So that buffering may well be getting in the way of the hGetLine function.